# How do I forward http request body with nginx

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I try to setup reverse proxy with nginx, now I can pass the request to the destination host but the http body get lost after pass the reverse proxy. Could anyone give me suggestion to config nginx to forward http body?

Here is my config file

```
  location /my/request/url/ {
    proxy_pass http://my/destination/host/_search;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
  }
```